# Can in-app billing use the previous ID's including versions changes to credit the users that have bought the previous version the new one?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app

We are deprecating an older .apk and the new one will have a different ID. Can we use in-app billing to query the users Google Play account and not charge them for the new one? I thought I read that you can do this by making a list of the previous ID's and then when the app sees them, it will not charge the user and then let them download the new version.

I.e., the old .apk has the following ID's associated to sales:

- ID v1: `com.yourname.here:1:1`
- ID v1: `com.yourname.here:1:2`
- ID v2: `com.yourname.here:1:3`
- ID v2: `com.yourname.here:1:4`

The new .apk will have a different ID: `com.myname.here`.

I want to make sure the people who have bought previous version won't get charged when they go to the Play Store to get the latest version. I only want people who have not previously bought it to get charged the full amount.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this with the API and maybe show a small example of it?

I see on [this page](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html), that Google leads me to believe you can do this with the bundle and the getPurchase request. Below is from the above URL, Step #2.

> `2.` When your application starts or user logs in, it's good practice to check with Google Play to determine what items are owned by the user. To query the user's in-app purchases, send a getPurchases request. If the request is successful, Google Play returns a Bundle containing a list of product IDs of the purchased items, a list of the individual purchase details, and a list of the signatures for the purchases.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, you can only query purchased items from the current package name. It would be nice if that wasn't true, but I haven't seen anything to indicate it.

Comment: I see on this page, http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html, that Google leads me to believe you can do this with the bundle and the getPurchase request. Step #2. When your application starts or user logs in, it's good practice to check with Google Play to determine what items are owned by the user. To query the user's in-app purchases, send a getPurchases request. If the request is successful, Google Play returns a Bundle containing a list of product IDs of the purchased items, a list of the individual purchase details, and a list of the signatures for the purchases.

Comment: Check the reference for `getPurchases()` [here.](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) It says "from this app" for all pertinent fields.

Comment: But the base of it is...The getPurchases() method

This method returns the current un-consumed products owned by the user. Table 5 lists the response data that is returned in the Bundle.

Comment: Yes, but where in that bundle do you expect purchases from other apps to be if every one of them says "from this app"? If you think it will work for you, then **try it**. If it does, be sure to post it as an answer here.